# JobScheduler issues android

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

The jobscheduler runs every 10 mins periodically. What I have to do to run the schedule as soon as the app runs and keeps running periodically every 10 mins. What happens now is that: after the app is installed, it takes 10 mins to run the schedule. How to make it run initially and then repeats in every 10 mins? I have code for updating data to the server in onStartJob(). But the upload time is from 7 min to 25 mins too. I want to upload data every 10 mins but it varies randomly. Why is that?

```
JobInfo jobInfo =
    new JobInfo.Builder(MYJOBID, jobService).setPeriodic(600000).
    setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY).
    setRequiresCharging(false).
    setRequiresDeviceIdle(false).
    setPersisted(true).
    setExtras(bundle).
    build();

int jobId = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
if(jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)>0){
    Toast.makeText(LiveTrack.this,
            "Successfully scheduled job: " + jobId,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(LiveTrack.this,
            "RESULT_FAILURE: " + jobId,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

.

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        new MyDownloadTask().execute();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to upload data every 10 mins but it varies randomly. Why is that?

The `JobScheduler` API makes no promise of repeating at exact intervals.

> But the upload time is from 7 min to 25 mins too.

According to `setPeriodic()` [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPeriodic(long)):

> You have no control over when within this interval this job will be executed, only the guarantee that it will be executed at most once within this interval.

Still, we should be getting a callback at most 20 minutes apart. Let's look at `JobInfo.Builder` [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/job/JobInfo.java). Starting at `setPeriodic(long)`:

```
 public Builder setPeriodic(long intervalMillis) {
        return setPeriodic(intervalMillis, intervalMillis);
 }
```

Ok it calls it's overloaded cousin. Which says:

> Specify that this job should recur with the provided interval and flex. The job can execute at any time in a window of flex length at the end of the period.

Wow so the flex length is also 10 minutes in our case? Not so fast:

```
/**
  * Specify that this job should recur with the provided interval and flex. The job can
  * execute at any time in a window of flex length at the end of the period.
  * @param intervalMillis Millisecond interval for which this job will repeat. A minimum
  *                       value of {@link #getMinPeriodMillis()} is enforced.
  * @param flexMillis Millisecond flex for this job. Flex is clamped to be at least
  *                   {@link #getMinFlexMillis()} or 5 percent of the period, whichever is
  *                   higher.
  */
```

> A minimum value of getMinPeriodMillis() is enforced.

:|

What is the minimum period you ask?

`MIN_PERIOD_MILLIS = 15 * 60 * 1000L;   // 15 minutes`

So your call to `setPeriodic(60000)` doesn't accomplish anything. Minimum period remains clamped to 15 minutes.

`JobScheduler` is not really meant to be used for exact repeating periods. In fact it was built because a majority of the apps were abusing the `AlarmManger` api which provides this (exact repeating) functionality.

Comment: hi.. thanks for the ans. There is a 'return false' statement in onStop() method. If I set it to true, it is not working (ie. the data are not updated in the server). Why is that?

Comment: @AmritaStha Thanks for accepting. I think you mean ```onStopJob()```. If you read the javadoc you'll see that when ```onStopJob()``` is called when your ```onStartJob()``` is likely to fail. Returning from ```onStopJob()``` is simply and indication to the system to retry you rjob or not. I think this a separate question in itself. I suggest  you ask another question for it with details.

Comment: Sorry that was for onStartJob()... If true is returned, the code inside it doesn't work.

Comment: @AmritaStha See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts. More details, code will help. The new question will have more visibility & other people might be able to provide better answers.

Comment: And also, please upvote if you find this answer correct and helpful :)